# How to type a function return type with dynamic key in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have a function that returns an object like so:

```js
// keyValue would be something like 'end', 'start' etc.

const getTimeAndDateSplit = (keyValue: string, isoDateString) => {
  // do time parsing

  return {
    [`${keyValue}Date`]: 'dd/mm/yyy',
    [`${keyValue}Time`]: 'hh:mm'
  }
}
```

Now I've tried to type this in so many different ways using generics, or simply just typing the variable type to no avail:

```js
const startTimeKeyValues: {
  startDate: string;
  startTime: string;
} = getTimeAndDateSplit("start", startTime);
// Type '{ [x: string]: string; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ startDate: string; startTime: string; }': startDate, startTimets(2739)
```

The return type is always `{ [x: string]: string }`

How can I go about typing the `getTimeAndDateSplit` so I can easily pass the return values, such as `getTimeAndDateSplit<"startDate", "startTime">`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this behavior with help of Record type.

See example:

```js
const record = <K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V) => ({ [key]: value }) as Record<K, V>;

const getTimeAndDateSplit = <T extends string>(keyValue: T) => ({
    ...record(`${keyValue}Date` as const, 'dd/mm/yyy' as const),
    ...record(`${keyValue}Time` as const, 'hh:mm' as const),
})

const startTimeKeyValues = getTimeAndDateSplit("start");
```

Because objects with computed string are evaluated to `{[prop: string]:any}` we should take responsibility and explicitly cast this object to `Record`.

If you don't like type casting, you can use overloadings:

```js
function record<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V): Record<K, V>
function record<K extends string, V>(key: K, value: V) {
    return ({ [key]: value })
}
```

But please keep in mind, using one overloading for function is a bad practive, it is practically the same as previous example.

Comment: Love this method!! I've been utilizing this quite a bit for dynamically creating return objects with specific names after I saw Redux Toolkit do this on their RTK Query.